# How to see the guest-cart in the webpage

Tags: checkout, cart, addtocart, shopping-cart-price-rules, shopping-cart

I successfully added a product with the api rest using and the access point '/rest/default/V1/guest-carts/:cart-id:/items'. Now, I need to show this guest-cart in the cart page of the client

Any idea?

Comment: It's not clear what Magento version you are using, but using the same access point with a GET request should return the data you need for that page https://devdocs.magento.com/redoc/2.3/guest-rest-api.html#operation/quoteGuestCartItemRepositoryV1GetListGet

Comment: Great thank-you, I can see products with this api.
Now, I need them in the cart page of the website. I guess It's something related to this website instead of the magento API, but I have to make sure there is not other way.

So, has Magento any access-point to send the cart made by the api to cart's page of the website?